# Configure Juniper M320 as Ethernet/STM transparent converter

Tags: networking, router, switch, juniper, mirroring

There is Juniper M320. We need to move **ALL** the traffic from one port to another. Everything that comes to one port goes to another and vice versa. No snooping or any other processing is required. One port is going to be Ethernet and another one is STM.

It seems that mirroring  might help, but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Bridge between STM and Ethernet.
Bridging requires to have compatible frame formats and addressing on both sides, which in case of Ethernet and STM is not the case.

You can either route the payload between the two systems or you can encapsulate (i.e. tunnel) Ethernet through STM or the other way around.